# How to send recurrence emails without using Power Automate?

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, recurrence, splistitem

I am using SharePoint Online and I have created one list with name Requests for store the data.

This list contains columns like Title, Description, Start Date, End Date, etc..

I have created an SPFx solution for inserting/updating/deleting data from the Requests list.

There is one column End Date in the Request list.

Now, I need to send a reminder email after 2 days of the End Date.

Can anyone suggest a way to send an email without using Power Automate (Flow)?

Thanks

Comment: you can create an azure function , if you have a large list and azure function will timeout before sending all email, try azure durable function, try and let me know how it works

Comment: Exactly, Power Automate is the best choice.